# Pass data between views

Tags: ios, xcode

As on picture below I want to have option of adding and editing a cell in table view. Clicking "+" or table cell it opens the other view, where user can fill in info:
I was told that using the "Exit" on the top of view (Top right of photo) you can easily handle all the information filled in. Unfortunately I can't find help in the internet because "Exit" is pretty common word in english.

Extra: If you could advice me easiest way to catch the data from clicked cell, to fill in text field for edit I would appreciate as well :)

[image]

Comment: Correct me if I have not understood the problem:
1. You want to pass the cell data to the new view.
2. The edited information on the second view should reflect on the corresponding cell.
 
Are these your questions?

Comment: Use the delegate pattern to catch that information

Comment: http://www.appcoda.com/storyboards-ios-tutorial-pass-data-between-view-controller-with-segue/

Follow this example this will give you data from your tableView to next view.

Comment: Do you store the data somehow? Core Data or so? Or just want to pass it?

Comment: 1. I choose add/edit -> I fill in text views -> click done -> new cell created/cell edited
2. clicking cell -> second view has text fields filled in already

Comment: First just pass it, but I want to use Core Data. 
But maybe dosen't make sense to split it to two parts and I should begin from creating Core Data, what you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use Unwind Segues first you have to create a unwind action in the ViewController you could go back to, this is:

Objective C:

```
- (IBAction)unwindToMainMenu:(UIStoryboardSegue*)sender
{
    UIViewController *sourceViewController = sender.sourceViewController;
    // Pull any data from the view controller which initiated the unwind segue.
}
```

Swift:

```
@IBAction func unwindToMainMenu(sender: UIStoryboardSegue)
{
    let sourceViewController = sender.sourceViewController
    // Pull any data from the view controller which initiated the unwind segue.
}
```

The name of this method could be whatever you want. Those are from Apple documentation.

You can trigger that action from a button in the ViewController. For that you have to ctrl-drag from the button to the "Exit" button (in the same ViewController) and it will display all the unwind actions.

You can pass data in two ways:

- Using `prepareForSegue`: When the button is pressed it will execute a `prepareForSegue` in the ViewController and you can pass the information you want to the "previous" viewController.
- Extract the information from the viewController: as in the above unwind actions you can access the viewController's information you need accessing the view controller with the property `sourceViewController` of the parameter `sender`.

I hope this helps.

You could find more information in the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2298/_index.html).
Also it is explained in WWDC 2012 video *Adopting Storyboards In Your App* (last 10 minutes talks about unwind segues)

Answer (score 0):

To pass data from one viewController to another by the cell that was selected you have to follow these steps:
 1. Get the content of the selected Cell in your first viewController.
 2. Create an instance of the second viewController with an editable attribute (in your case let's say the Name Label).
 3. Set that attribute to the content from step one. (below is a sample of the main method you would focus on in the first viewController)

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tblView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  NSString *str = cell.textLabel.text;
  SecondViewController *secondVC = [[SecondViewController alloc]init];
  secondVC.nameLabel.text = str;
  }
```

Does this make sense?